# Android: Custom Retrofit Callback, how can I prevent an implementation from doing its stuff

Tags: java, android, retrofit

sorry for weird title not sure how to summarise my problem but I think it will be clear once I explain the code.

**Background**

Without putting a lot of retrofit code in, I have some API call that goes like this

```
 public static void getListOfFood(@NonNull Callback<FoodList> callback) {
        Call<FoodList> call = RetrofitClient.get().getFood();
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
```

And somewhere in my fragment I have this

```
NetworkService.getListOfFood(new Callback<FoodList>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<FoodList> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                        //Do Something cool
                       }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                }
            });
```

So the problem I have is, lets say this fragment has been destroyed (user navigated back), the response is still delivered and I get null pointers because it is invoking code in onResponse grrrrr!

**Core Problem**

Fragments have a method is called isRemoving which is an indicator if the fragment is being removed so I could wrap onResponse and onFailure with an if statement but it gets messy when there are many other requests

**My Solution and problem I need help with**

I made an abstract class which implements Call

```
 public abstract class MyCustomCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private WeakReference<Fragment> mWeakFragment;

    public MyCustomCallback(Fragment fragment){
        this.mWeakFragment = new WeakReference<>(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<T> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Fragment fragment = mWeakFragment.get();
        if(fragment != null && !fragment.isRemoving()){
            return;
        }else{
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

And then in my fragment I create an implementation of this and call super

```
 NetworkService.getListOfFood(new MyCustomCallbackk<FoodList>(this) {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<FoodList> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    super.onResponse(response, retrofit);
                    if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    super.onFailure(t);
                }
            });
```

How can I prevent the implementation onResponse from being called if the super call if statement is false?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Any solutions found?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Fragment.isAdded()` to check whether the fragment is a currently added to its activity. You can read more on this [Fragment.isAdded()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded())

Answer (score -1):

You can block the interface while the request is being executing, thus, the user can't navigate back. For this, you can show a ProgressDialog.

Example code:

```
ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "dialog title",
"dialog message", false);

NetworkService.getListOfFood(new Callback<FoodList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<FoodList> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                 if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    //Do Something cool
                 }
                 // Close the progress dialog when we obtain a response
                 progress.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                // Handle the error
                ....

                // Close the progress dialog when we obtain an error
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

The user will have to wait until the request has finished

Comment: I consider preventing the user from pressing back as a bad practice. Instead you should let the user press back and cancel the request callback to avoid doing any UI stuff on a destroyed view.